# Can Elastic Search plugin have more than one onModule function

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I need to add analyzers and REST end point in my plugin .

So for analyzer , **onModule()** function would look like :

```
public void onModule(AnalysisModule module) {
    module.addAnalyzer("new-analyzer", NewAnalyzerProvider.class);
}
```

And for REST end point, **onModule()** function would look like :

```
public void onModule(RestModule module) {
    module.addRestAction(NewRestAction.class);
}
```

Now, can I make a plugin which can have both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly ok to provide several overloaded `onModule` methods for each module you want to support in your plugin.

Note, however, that the `onModule()` methods will be deprecated in ES 5 and your plugin will simply need to implement [`AnalysisPlugin`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/920bd0cf68fde174efd00793ef628e03ada047b4/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugins/AnalysisPlugin.java) and [`ActionPlugin`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commits/920bd0cf68fde174efd00793ef628e03ada047b4/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugins/ActionPlugin.java) instead.